# visual studio 2019 migrating from package.config no option to perform the migration and no errors

Tags: package, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I picked a project I'm working on, clicked Migrate to package reference, the migration screen popped up but the OK button is greyed out, no errors are displayed and I cannot proceed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and it turned out to be because one of the packages was not on any currently connected nuget feed.  I changed the version of that package in packages.config to one I know is available, saved package.config, and ran the migration again.  The OK button is now available to click.